# Uncaught SyntaxError: Bootstrap.esm.min.js:6

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

there is a .php file I want to use jquery on, before I do more with it, I wanted to try it out first to see if it would work with the page. when I click on submit the javascript totally does nothing on the page and below are the errors on the console and the nature of my code.

html page

```
 <div class="col-8">

        <form  action="bar.php " method="post">
   get fields:</br>

 <input type="text" name="goods"id="barid"><br>
 <br>

  <input type="submit" value=" click" name="submit">
</form>




   </div>
 </br>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>


</html>
```

bar.php

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST["click"])){
   
    $s = $_POST['goods'];

    $fields= test_input($s);

}

function test_input($name) {
    $data = trim($name);
    $data = stripslashes($name);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($name);
    return $name;
  }




echo "<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     

         alert ('$goods');
     });

 </script>"; 

var_dump($goods); //this works quite okay

?>
```

and this is the error I have on console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Bootstrap.esm.min.js:6 Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured this out after much research; I moved the jquery link from my footer file to my header file and below is the end product of that..and it started working.

```
 <head>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.esm.min.js" integrity="sha384-sKZy8g2KJhBTFCD6cIg8d4EifJxaa8c/iYIERdeKorHWhAgZgQOfqOKMe3xBqye1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/paperpdf.css">
    <title>$title</title>
  </head>









 </div>
 </br>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>


</html>
```